# Rstudio - connect to HDInsight Spark Cluster SparkR

Tags: r, azure, apache-spark, rstudio, sparkr

I am using RStudio on my local laptop and trying to connect to an existing, remote HDInsight Spark Cluster.

A couple questions:

1) Do I need to have RStudio installed on the HDInsight Spark Cluster?

2) How do I connect local RStudio to a remote Spark Cluster?  I've been looking at the SparkR docs [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sparkr.html) but it doesn't seem to give a connect example (ie URL, credentials, etc.)?

Comment: were your questions answered? Can we connect to a local rstudio to a remote spark cluster using https://CLUSTERNAME.azurehdinsight.net/rstudio/. if so how does the authentication double work?

Answer (score 2):

HDInsight includes an R Server option to be integrated into your HDInsight cluster. This option allows R scripts to use Spark and MapReduce to run distributed computations.

For more details, refer “[Get started using R Server on HDInsight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-r-server-get-started)”.